# SQL COMMANDS to add a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, addition, drop

I have customer table with column First_Name and Last_Name of Customer, I want to combine these two column with one Customername and add this Customer_Name column in the table also .and want to remove first_name and Last_name column from the table .

```
select First_name, Last_name, concat(First_name,' ',Last_name) as Customer_Name from Customer;

alter table Customer add CustomerName varchar(50);

insert into Customer (CustomerName) values (First_name + ' ' + Last_name);

select * from Customer;

alter table Customer add CustomerName1 varchar(50);

insert into Customer (CustomerName1) values (convert(varchar(50),First_name + ' ' + Last_name);
```

these are the command which i already tried but error

Comment: Please share the errors you have got, also tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: Column name invalid, and I am working it on SQL Server management studio...

Comment: Why are you inserting don't you want an `update`?

Comment: actually I want to add a new column in the table as want the vales from the existing columns which are already in table like First_name and last_name of the customer want to combine these two column and make a new column

Comment: @PrachiYadav SQL Server Management Studio is a GUI IDE for interacting with databases, not a database engine unto itself. I assume you mean your database is _SQL Server_?

Comment: This is such a bad idea, you dont' want to do this. Or you'll be writing to stackoverflow in a couple of weeks (or days) asking on how to split names by space

Comment: How will happen when someone changes their last name (like in most countries when a woman traditionally marries) and you need to update the last name?  If you get rid of the last name column then you're stuck writing an algorithm to update your combo column.  That's why you keep data atomic, in it's own column.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you *not* create a dedicated column that combines the two name fields, and I would *certainly not* advise you drop the original fields. You're always going to be better off storing data in atomic fields (i.e. first and last name) rather than combined fields. For instance, you can *construct* the value for `CustomerName` from the `first_name` and `last_name` fields, but if you then *drop* those fields, and decide you want to change the way you treat a combined name, you're out of luck. Or rather you have to rely on string jiu jitsu to hope you can extract the original fields from eachother. There's not really any need to remove the individual fields; if you don't want to use them for a given query, just don't use them.

I would recommend you create a [computed_column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) like so:

```
alter table Customer
add CustomerName as first_name + ' ' + last_name
```

Here, the field is entirely constructed from the values of `first_name` and `last_name`, and you never had to throw away those nice, atomic columns. Plus, if in the future you decide you want to change how `CustomerName` gets built, you just re-create the computed column with a different expression. You can even use the `persisted` keyword on the computed column if, say, you want to index the newly created `CustomerName` field.

Comment: You assume all countries have a first and last name, or that the name has only one word. Or that the order is always the same. That's not the case. For example, Arabic names can be quite long and *can't* be split in first and last name. Chinese names are in reverse order. That's why airlines use a single Passenger Name field

Comment: I too have read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). My argument is more that if there are conditions under which the first and last name fields are valuable, throwing them away may be premature. Also, if the OP is dealing with Arabic and Chinese names, those datatypes should probably be changed to `nvarchar`

Answer (score -1):

Here how to do it :

Add CustomerName column :

```
ALTER TABLE Customer add CustomerName varchar(50);
```

Then, rather than inserting, you must update:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET CustomerName = First_name + ' ' + Last_name;
```

Then drop columns :

```
ALTER TABLE Customer DROP COLUMN First_name;

ALTER TABLE Customer DROP COLUMN Last_name;
```